# Attach and debug external C# code in a unity game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-debugging

I am working with a unity game, but much of it's code (including mods) is actually c# code in separate library projects that are not part of the unity project itself.

These assemblies are loaded with reflection and entry points etc are looked up also with reflection.

Currently when I attempt to debug this code, open in visual studio, I can attach to the game but no breakpoints will hit and symbols do not show as loaded. Is this actually suppose to work, and be possible, or some unity limitation?

Comment: Check out this answer, [Debug dynamically loaded assembly in Visual Studio .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295807/debug-dynamically-loaded-assembly-in-visual-studio-net)

Comment: I do have .pdbs and have tried to point vs to them and load symbols in the way im use to when debugging normal .net, it just doesn't work. I suspect either 1. this just doesn't work at all for unity, for some reason 2. it does if you do everything exactly such-and-such way

Comment: Just want to confirm, do you mean all of the code can't hit breakpoints or just assemblies(or packages) can't hit breakpoints?